# Youtube API quota exceeded with 1 video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I try to insert a video in nodeJS to Youtube, and I got this error :

> { errors:    [ { domain: 'youtube.quota',
>          reason: 'quotaExceeded',
>          message: 'The request cannot be completed because you have exceeded your [quota](/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota).'
>   } ],   code: 403,   message: 'The request cannot be completed because
>   you have exceeded your quota.' }

EDIT : this is when I use Auth with an existing Token, I get token from https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and use it in my code. I tried with different accounts, can't upload video but I can insert item in playlist for example.

Here is my code (nodeJS) :

```
var req = Youtube.videos.insert({
    "resource": {
        // Video title and description
        "snippet": {
            "title": "Test",
            "description": "Test video upload via YouTube API"
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "private"
        }
    }, 
    "part": "snippet,status,id", 
    "media": {
        "body": fs.createReadStream('./test.mp4')
    }
}, function (err, data) {
....
```

The video is 600 Ko... How can I see or update quotas ? I use OAuth auth, for example I can insert elements in my playlist with no problems, but I can't upload videos. Do I need something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a reference of your error from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#gdata.CoreErrorDomain).

About the [quota](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota):

> The YouTube Data API uses a quota to ensure that developers use the
>   service as intended and do not create applications that unfairly
>   reduce service quality or limit access for others. All API requests,
>   including invalid requests, incur at least a one-point quota cost. You
>   can find the quota available to your application in the [Developers
>   Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).
>
> Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota
>   allocation of 1 million units per day, an amount sufficient for the
>   overwhelming majority of our API users. Default quota, which is
>   subject to change, helps us optimize quota allocations and scale our
>   infrastructure in a way that is more meaningful to our API users. You
>   can see your quota usage on the [Usage](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/usage) tab for the API in the
>   Google Developer's Console.
>
> *Note: If you reach the quota limit, you can request additional quota on the [Quotas](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/quotas) tab in the Developer's Console.*

Comment: I know about quota, but as I said, I got this message after only 1 video upload of 600 Ko... I go this message only if I use authentification with token (token got from Google console), not with OAuth2 login.